# Do Evasion and Protection work against non-physical damage?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

The mage's specializations in the elemental trees grant, with 32 points spent, a protection from a single element for the whole party. Are the resistances the only way to protect your characters from magical and non physical damage, or are Evasion and Protection also factored in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki suggests that neither are effective against elemental damage.

["Protection provides little benefit to the rear members of your party since the majority of the attacks will be elemental, rather than physical."](http://grimrockwiki.net/wiki/Protection)

["Evasion affects the character's chance of evading physical attacks."](http://grimrockwiki.net/wiki/Evasion)